# Is it possible to see TCP traffic between two remote hosts in wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I am trying to debug TCP communication between two embedded devices, only one of which is under my control. I want to see what is going on in Wireshark, but I see nothing. Is it even possible to see traffic between remote hosts (but on the same switch) in Wireshark?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not when between you and these hosts there is a SWITCH (as opposed to a HUB).  A switch will only forward packets to the port on which the destination host is attached, whereas a hub propagates all packets it sees to all ports.

What you want can be achieved by (temporarily) installing a hub on which your computer and the two systems that need to be sniffed are connected.

EDIT: as MattH said in a comment, on many higher end switches there's a mirroring feature that allows you to use 1 port of the switch to sniff on another port.  You could ask your network guy if your switch has such a feature, and get access to that feature for debugging purposes.

Comment: some switches have a mirror-port feature, which is a possibility for the packet capture if one has administrative access and the feature.

Comment: **You can see traffic on a switch** if you do ARP poisoning. If I remember correctly you can use `ettercap` to do this and then see the traffic with `wireshark`.

Comment: @EricdesCourtis technically you are right but that's often not really a practical thing to do (and could potentially cause you trouble if you try that on a corporate network).

Comment: Like what kind of trouble exactly? This reminds me of when people thought using nmap was hacking. Absolutely ridiculous. If you have a legitimate use for the tool use it. If you are doing this in a highly secure environment with IDS equipment it might be worth letting them know ahead of time. But then again I think the same rules would apply to sniffing and adding a hub or using nmap.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your switch. Some switches have a feature called '[port mirroring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring)' which allows allows you to mirror all the traffic on particular physical port to another port.

The cheapest way to do it would be to pick up a basic network [hub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch#Layer_1_hubs_versus_higher-layer_switches). By default this will replicate all incoming and outgoing traffic on a single port on all other ports.

Comment: It is not the cheapest way see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can see **any IP traffic on a switch even without port mirroring** if you use a technique called [ARP spoofing](http://openmaniak.com/ettercap_arp.php). You can accomplish this using a tool like [ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net/). I use this technique to troubleshoot VOIP traffic between a PBX and an IP Phone. Once the ARP spoofing is started you will see any or all IP traffic on wireshark. If you doubt the legitimacy of this solution see `Legitimate usage` on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) wikipedia page.

Comment: Please provide **valid** reasons for voting this answer down.